# DocuSign Web Admin - Associating template roles to users

Tags: docusignapi

Use case:

My Template  has 2 placeholder roles with signing order as below:

```
1) otherFirmSignerRole

2) myCompanySignerRole
```

Currently on a working poc model I associate (programmatically using rest api) the firm role to the user who logins to our application and fills out the form which generates the embedded signing url from template. This user has the ability to re-assign.

Once the firmRole signing is done, a signing request email is sent to a generic distribution list/inbox where only users with authority to sign as role-2  has access to.

There could be scenarios where the user who fills out the application form is not the one authorized to sign as firmRole. Is our application admin work flow supposed to manage these role associations?

However, is there a way we could manage users to template roles association from web admin interface? Or given the use-case is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

How do you manage that today? When a user fills out this form (presumably on paper now?), how do you know they are authorized to do so?

My gut feel is that this logic would need to be managed in your application before calling DocuSign.

Comment: You are right, currently on paper form there is no auth validation possible. However, we were looking into having some kind of user/template role associations to bring in some validations with digital signature.

Comment: An option could be to define a signing group for firm users, if you know exactly who is authorized to fill out the form. You could add this signing group as the firmRole recipient. But this means anyone in that group could fill it out and they will all receive the notification to sign. You could use this type of recipient for the CompanyRole as it sounds like there is a defined group of possible signers. I guess the short answer to your question is no, DocuSign doesn't manage user/role associations and most likely it'd need to be managed outside.

Comment: ok thanks. I will look into exploring more of the signing group feature to see if it can serve a solution.

Comment: I'm trying to create a signing group on the demo site account. Is 'Group' different from 'signing group'. I can create a new group, but when trying to add it as 'Person' recipient on template, it doesn't show up

Comment: This is likely not turned on for you as part of your account featureset. If you're comfortable putting your demo account ID up here, I could turn this feature on the backend. You can then remove or edit the comment, although it really isn't a security issue as no one can do anything with that number.

Comment: Sorry got side tracked with other issues.Anyways, one question I have though, so for real production environment, does this feature require any additional account privileges than the normal account? Whats the process for prod environment?

Comment: This feature is only supported in the Enterprise or Premium plans, so if you are on one of those you could contact DocuSign about switching it on in production. We could switch it on for you in demo any time for testing purposes.

Comment: Done, let me know if that works for you. You should see a new option for "Account Signing Groups" in the Groups screen next time you log in. There is also another alternative called "Any Signer", which basically emulates a distro list with a common email address amongst different users, but each of those will need to be setup as an individual user in DocuSign. With Signing Groups, you can add accountless signers as well.